AWS Amplify Setup Issues for us-east-1 region with friend in thailand
We are currently facing some challenges with setting up AWS Amplify on my friend's laptop, and we could really use some help!
Details:
Our project is set up in the us-east-1 region on AWS and Amplify.
My friend, who we are trying to help set this up, is currently in Thailand.
We are encountering issues during the setup process, and we are wondering if the geographic location could be causing these problems.
Issue:
We followed the account setup steps from the official AWS Amplify documentation successfully many times, but when running npx ampx sandbox, we get the following error in the terminal:
PS C:\Users\Mikes-Laptop\Documents\GitHub\AWS-first-project> npx ampx sandbox
Amplify Sandbox                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           Identifier:   Mikes-Laptop
Stack:        amplify-default-MikesLaptop-sandbox-b34df000d4
To specify a different sandbox identifier, use --identifier
Error: You must either specify a list of Stacks or the --all argument
Caused By: You must either specify a list of Stacks or the --all argument
[Sandbox] Watching for file changes...
Questions:
Has anyone else experienced similar issues when working from a different geographic location than their AWS region?
Are there specific settings or configurations we should look into to resolve these issues?
Is the geographic location likely to be causing these problems, or could it be related to something else?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance for your support!
Followed the https://docs.amplify.aws/nextjs/start/account-setup/ many times even emptied my .aws folder and restarted it.
